# Encoding and reading ID3 tags

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm reading mp3 ID3 tags using ffmpeg, short example:

```
AVDictionaryEntry* tag = av_dict_get(fc->metadata, "title", NULL, 0)
std::string title(tag->value);
```

In what way can I get information about the encoding of the read value? I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you need to? I would have expected ffmpeg to handle the decoding if needed.

Comment: If so, what's the resulting encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it should be UTF-8:

> Like all strings in FFmpeg, metadata is assumed to be UTF-8 encoded Unicode.

Quote comes from [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__metadata__api.html).